# How to implement pessimistic locking in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

There is a table called Accounts.The table structure looks like:

```
 AccountID  AccountName  AccountTotalMoney

   1           Stsven          3000
```

The account(where AccountID=1) was shared by many users.

So when a user updates the account(locking the account),I would like to prevent others updating the account.

I have visited

[6 ways of doing locking in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt#How%20can%20we%20solve%20concurrency%20problems)

But I do not understand yet.Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On revisiting your post, I'm pretty sure "pessimistic concurrency" is the solution you want instead of "locking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TransactionScope to implement pessimistic locking (change isolation level)

I think this post can help: [Setting the IsolationLevel using the System.Transactions TransactionScope.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/07/27/199261.aspx)

Be aware "pessimistic locking" mentioned in the link you posted is different concept of "pessimistic concurrency". Make sure it is the thing you want.